# How to set Google Map in android using Fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I set up google map using FragmentActivty (`public class MyGoogleMap extends FragmentActivity { }`, Now I want to set up google map using Fragment. (`public class MyGoogleMap extends Fragment { }` ). Is it possible, If yes and if you have any idea than please share with me. Thanks.

Comment: refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Yes it is very possible. There is not much to add however beyond what is provided in the doc linked to by @DixitPatel. Just follow the steps there.

Comment: @DixitPatel i am trying and thanks for your answer

Comment: Why not use the existing `SupportMapFragment`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a frame for map in which it will be added in your xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map_container">

<!-- The map fragments will go here --> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't include class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in xml either in your fragment class do get it manually inside onActivityCreated

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, fragment).commit();
    }


/***at this time google play services is not initialized so get map and add what ever you want to it in onResume() or onStart() **/
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (map == null) {
            map = fragment.getMap();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)));
        }
}
```